# Group by and keep rows within dataset by ID where a condition is met and also keep row immediately below if an alternative condition is met

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataset such as below:

```
df <- 
  read.table(textConnection("ID   Condition1   Condition2
A 1 0
A 1 1 
A 0 1
A 1 0
A 0 0 
A 0 1
B 1 1
B 0 1
C 1 0
C 0 0 
D 1 0
D 0 1
D 1 1 
D 0 0
"), header=TRUE)
```

I am looking to group by ID and filter to keep rows based on below conditions:

1. If a value of '1' is in column 'Condition1' then the row is retained
2. If a value of '1' is in column 'Condition2' then that row is also kept if it is immediately below a row that has a '1' in Condition1 above it.

Rows may have any number of combinations of 1s and 0s in the two columns. So for the below example, expected output would be:

| ID | Condition1 | Condition2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| D | 1 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 1 |
| D | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter` and `lag`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  filter(Condition1 == 1 | (Condition2 == 1 & lag(Condition1 == 1)))
```

Output:

```r
   ID Condition1 Condition2
1   A          1          0
2   A          1          1
3   A          0          1
4   A          1          0
5   B          1          1
6   B          0          1
7   C          1          0
8   D          1          0
9   D          0          1
10  D          1          1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
i <- df$Condition1 == 1       #If a value of '1' is in column 'Condition1'
j <- c(FALSE,                 #First row
       df$Condition2[-1] == 1 #If a value of '1' is in column 'Condition2'
       & i[-length(i)]        #if it is immediately below a row that has a '1' in Condition1 above it
       & df$ID[-length(i)] == df$ID[-1]) #group by ID

df[i | j,]  #Combine both i and j with or to subset
#   ID Condition1 Condition2
#1   A          1          0
#2   A          1          1
#3   A          0          1
#4   A          1          0
#7   B          1          1
#8   B          0          1
#9   C          1          0
#11  D          1          0
#12  D          0          1
#13  D          1          1
```